# React, recovering from error when navigating to different page

Tags: reactjs

When there's an error, react fails to render and page looks blank.

I hit browser back button or any other button that will results in navigating to a different page expecting to see a content, but screen is still empty.

How do I recover from error in React.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I recover from error in React.js?

You can use `Error Boundaries` which are React *components* that catch errors in their child component tree. You can also define a `fallback UI` to display users.

They are very similar to `catch` block, but they are `declarative`.

See [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are new to this, check for the error in browser console, as react makes dom level manipulation, so if any error comes, it fails to render the page. checkout the error concepts for handling the react applications. As a beginner level, try resolving the code issues while developing React application